# why doesn't a marshalled object retain the values modified inside the native code?

Tags: c#, marshalling

I am sure there is a simple answer, but I couldn't find it after some research. I read and proved (unless what I wrote is wrong) that automatically marshalled structure passed by reference (or classes) allocated in the managed memory, are correctly read and written by the native code, however once the code execution returns to the managed layer, the values changed inside the native code are not retained. Here an example:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public class DirtyWordsCheckResult
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 1024)]
    public string replace_string;
    public EnumDirtyWordsType dirty_type;

    public DirtyWordsCheckResult()
    {
        replace_string = new string(' ', 1024);
    }
}

public enum EnumDirtyWordsType
{
    kDirtyWordsTypeNormalAllowWords = 0,   // normal allow words
    kDirtyWordsTypeEvil = 1,               // illegal,can not be displayed
    kDirtyWordsTypeSensitive = 2,          // legal, but contain sensitive
}

public override EResult DirtyWordsFilter(string words, bool replace_sensitive, out DirtyWordsCheckResult check_result)
{
    check_result = new DirtyWordsCheckResult();
    var result = Utils.DirtyWordsFilter(utils_, words, replace_sensitive, check_result);
    return result;
}
```

the native function DirtyWordsFilter does get correctly the allocated object and can write in it without problems, however the values are not retained.

Now I am aware that I can use Marshal.AllocHGlobal to pass a preallocated IntPTR, therefore I am not looking for a solution, I am just curious to understand why the original mechanism doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The struct you use is not *blittable*.  An expensive word that means that the native layout is not the same as the managed layout.  The string causes it.  Not just because of the CharSet, a .NET string does not look anything like char[].   That requires the pinvoke marshaller to create a copy of the correct size before passing a pointer to it that the native code can use.

But it does *not* by default copy the modified struct back.  You have to put `[Out]` on the parameter to make it change its mind.  We can't see the [DllImport] declaration but it ought to resemble:

```
[DllImport(...)]
private static extern EResult DirtyWordsFilter(..., [Out] DirtyWordsCheckResult check_result);
```

The pinvoke marshaller has no specific knowledge of the data flow, not even if you use `ref` or `out` in the declaration (normally present for a struct declaration).  It merely sees the argument being passed by reference and assumes `[In]` as the default.  Usually a correct and optimal guess, not here.  Fwiw, do note that Pack=1 is almost never correct, it needs to match the packing used in native code and its default is 8 as well.  Happens to not matter in this specific case.

Comment: is it the [out keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) or the [out attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.outattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) that should be used. You seem to use both in your answer.

Comment: Quote: "You have to put `[Out]` on the parameter".  Brackets == attribute.

Comment: Ok, I was having trouble understanding the first 3 sentences of the last paragraph at first. I get what you mean now.